# Python Selenium TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, selenium

Been stuck on an error for quite some time so I hope somebody can help!

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')

for url in urls:

   hopeful = url.get_attribute('ping')

   print(hopeful)

   actual = hopeful[31:]

   driver.get(actual)   

time.sleep(4)

driver.close
```

When i run the code i get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

In the output i am getting URLs alongside some unwanted aspects beforehand, which is why i am trying to use the substring function to remove the first 31 characters, which would leave me with my URL allowing me to pass it into `driver.get()`.

Is there a way i can remove the program from returning and attempting to substring `none`, which is resulting in the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be naive but why not check for None?
You did not provide the exact line that triggers the error, so I suppose it is `hopefull[31]`.

```
urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
for url in urls:
   hopeful = url.get_attribute('ping')
   if hopeful and len(hopeful) > 31:
       print(hopeful)
       actual = hopeful[31:]
       if actual.startswith('uk.linkedin.com'):
           driver.get(actual)   
time.sleep(4)
driver.close
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i am new to Python programming so often the issues are sorted with simple fixes such as this ha! 
One final question, is there a way for me to specify for this line: driver.get(actual), to only iterate over the ones which have a string of "https://uk.linkedin.com" at the start? As otherwise i result in a "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" error

Comment: Thank you so much once again. The amount this has helped is immense! I have one final (probably again very simple) request after which i should be question free. I have noticed that my searchable string is all the characters that come before "&ved". Characters in the string after this render the string unsearchable. Is there a way for me to capture anything that begins with 'uk.linkedin.com', encapsulating all characters up to but not including "&ved" and any characters that come after? Once again I really appreciate your help on this

Comment: Am resulting in a weird issue. When i run my code and print my output, the URLs of which i would like to enter print perfectly. If i manually copy and paste them into a search bar, each of them returns the result I am hoping for. However if i use the driver.get method, only the first one opens and i am recieving a "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" error. Is there a reason/ workaround for this? @Risadinha

Comment: @DrijVyas please create a new question for that where you provide more details.